# doing a rails test:system that always returns no error even if I purposely made it an errof

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara

Example 1:

```
click_on 'Add Cart'
assert_no_selector "#empty-cart" #note #empty-cart should be dynamically created since we added an item

 accept_confirm do 
   click_on 'Empty Cart'
 end

assert_selector #"empty-cart"  #note: empty-cart should no longer be present since it was dynamically removed
```

but somehow I run the test and everything is fine.

Example 2

```
click_on 'Add Cart'

visit my_url
assert_no_selector "#empty-cart" 

 accept_confirm do 
   click_on 'Empty Cart'
 end

visit my_url
assert_selector #"empty-cart"
```

By forcing a reload, the test script somehow is able to detect that the assertion is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm assuming you meant the #s to be inside the quotes in the two examples you give - otherwise they're just creating comments

The concept you're missing is that all actions in the browser occur asynchronously.  This means that when `accept_confirm` returns, the confirm modal has been clicked but any actions that triggers are not guaranteed to have occurred yet. Therefore when `assert_selector "#empty-cart"` is run it is highly likely that element is still on the page and the assertion will immediately pass.

For your second example you have a similar issue. Clicking on 'Add Cart' and then immediately calling `visit` is likely to either abort the `visit` call or have the `visit` call processed in parallel and not actually see the results of 'Add Cart'. You need to add an assertion to confirm that the 'Add Cart' actions have completed before moving on. Something like

```
click_on 'Add Cart'
assert_no_selector '#empty-cart' # or maybe assert_text 'Item added to cart!' etc.
visit my_url
```

Comment: Okay basically it's supposed to empty the cart via ajax and after deleting the cart the Empty Cart (#empty-cart) button / link will be removed/re-rendered to be empty. Doing the visit_url works but I guess it defeats the purpose of testing if the whole thing works with ajax as it should be on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Berimbolo You should be checking for things that change.  ie. if something goes away check that it's gone.  Trying to force a fail of your test by testing for the presence of the thing that's going away isn't going to work because it will likely still be there at the time you call the assertion, and hence the assertion will pass.  If you call an assertion that the item is gone it will wait up to `Capybara.default.max_wait_time` seconds for that assertion to become true, thereby giving the actions triggered on the page time to occur

Comment: sorry I didnt realize the comments weren't going to be formatted!

Comment: @Berimbolo Assuming that clicking 'Add Cart' adds the '#empty-cart' element to the page and clicking it removes the element - Yes.  However, there really is no need to actually check for the element '#empty-cart' because the user doesn't care about element names on the page, they care about functionality.  
`click_on 'Add Cart'
accept_confirm do 
  click_on 'Empty Cart'
end
assert_no_selector(:link_or_button,  'Empty Cart')`

Will test all the same things without worrying about the element ids

Comment: Yes basically Im looking for things that change by clicking cart, I am asserting that that the Empty cart button has appeared, and by clicking Empty Cart, asserting again that it has disappeared. Out of curiosity I flipped the code and wondered why its not returning an error.

Comment: @Berimbolo It didn't fail because of asynchronicity -- If you put a sleep of a few seconds (to let the page actions occur) ahead of your flipped assertions then it would return an error.

Comment: Got it, i added sleep(5) before the last assertion and it was able to catch the error. Would you suggest that the best option is to put sleep whey doing ajax/dom test?

Comment: @Berimbolo No - you shouldn't have sleep in your test.  There is no need to write an intentionally failing test.  Just set `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to an appropriate amount for the hardware you're testing on and write tests that you expect to pass.  Capybaras built-in waiting/retrying behavior will then handle the asynchronous nature of things.  The one "tricky" things is that if you're changing to a new page where you expect something not to show up you need a positive assertion for something on the page before your negative assertion (to ensure the page has loaded).